# Script SQL, para Inserir e-mails em uma tabela, e depois altera-los

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu tenho um script, que faz inserções randômicas de e-mails em uma tabela, após essas inserções, preciso encontrar uma maneira de verificar novamente esses e-mails inseridos, e alterá-los

Essa é uma parte do Script, eu passo para ele uma quantidade de e-mails (por exemplo 5), e ele vai criar 5 e-mail (kaue1@email.com.br....kaue5@email.com.br), o que eu não estou conseguindo é após essas inserções, substituir esses e-mails em um UPDATE. Preciso substituir esses mesmos e-mails inseridos, por outros e-mail, como (kaue5@email.com.br....kaue10@email.com.br)

```
FOR i IN 1..V_QTD_EMAILS LOOP
INSERT INTO G_CADASTRO.PX_EMAIL
  (
  ID,
  CD_DADOS_XXX_XXX_XXX,
  EMAIL,
  DT_INCLUSAO,
  CD_USUARIO
  )
VALUES
  (
    (SELECT MAX(ID) + 1
    FROM G_CADASTRO.PPX_EMAIL),
    V_CD_DADOS_PX_ESTAB,
    'KAUE' || i || '@EMAIL.COM.BR',
    SYSDATE,

    4993
  );
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
```

Eu tentei incluir esse bloco, mas não funcionou:

```
FOR i IN 5..V_QTD_EMAILS loop
  UPDATE G_CADASTRO.PX_EMAIL
     SET EMAIL = 'MATHEUS_' || i || '@EMAIL.COM.BR'
    WHERE CD_DADOS_PX_ESTAB = V_CD_DADOS_PX_ESTAB
END LOOP;
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Faça o mesmo loop do insert, e user o seu EMAIL  no `where  EMAIL   =  'KAUE' || i || '@EMAIL.COM.BR' and CD_USUARIO = 4993`  e no seu set use  `SET EMAIL = 'MATHEUS_' || i + 5 || '@EMAIL.COM.BR'`

Comment: mas o update vai acontecer quando ? você chama o script novamente depois, passando 10 por exemplo ? ou só chama o script 1x e ele dá o insert e em seguida já dá o update ?

Comment: Rovann Linhalis, exatamente isso, o script roda uma única vez, então o insert e o update ocorrem no mesmo script, então o teste é finalizado. Na verdade o fluxo ocorre assim: Verifica a Tabela Pai >> Se já existe e-mail, apaga tudo, e insere novos dados, Então depois esses dados deve sofrer um UPDATE, que altera os e-mails

Comment: Por que você não insere os emails corretamente no primeiro loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoa, resolvi com o seguinte SCRIPT:

```
FOR i IN 1..V_QTD_EMAILS loop
  UPDATE G_CADASTRO.PX_EMAIL
      SET EMAIL = 'TSTALTERACAO_' || i || '@EMAIL.COM.BR'
      WHERE EMAIL = 'KAUE' || i || '@EMAIL.COM.BR'
      AND CD_USUARIO = 4993;
END LOOP;
```

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos

Comment: marca a resposta como aceita ;)

Comment: Para marcar minha própria resposta, preciso esperar dois dias :\